# How do I cancel or redo a production deployment in my clerk dashboard?

Tags: authentication, clerk

I chose to deploy the clone copy and got stuck at the step of Email server initialization. Is there a way for me to complete the deployment or I have a channel to cancel the deployment? I've been stuck here for almost 48 hours [dashboard1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdvfw.png) [dashboard2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpbX9.png)

I'm hoping I can redeploy or will it work if I clean some project configuration?

Comment: Hey, did you find a fix to this?